# How do you install after download?

Tags: installation

After I download the Ubuntu file how do I install on my desk top computer?

I am completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to burn it on to a DVD and boot from it. Follow this Official Ubuntu instructions from [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) for installation.

If you are willing to boot with a USB stick, follow this Official Ubuntu documentation from [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

IF you are to make a dual boot, follow this Official Ubuntu Documentation from [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

If you are willing to make the installation inside Windows with Wubi, follow this [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) Official documentation.